# Contact Merge Exception

Tags: dmlexception

I am trying to merge two contacts with different accounts associated with them. I have given a Role to the account owner but whenever I try to merge them I am getting this error:

> Failed to merge the contacts.
>   Error: System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id 0031100000llUWJAA2; first error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, A portal user's contact record must include an organization.
>   Furthermore, the owner of the organization must be associated with a role.: [AccountId].

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. can you please add more details and specifics to your question so that someone can answer.

Comment: I am trying to merge two contacts with different accounts associated with them but whenever i am trying to merge them i am getting this error : Failed to merge the contacts. Error: System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id 0031100000llUWJAA2; first error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, A portal user's contact record must include an organization. Furthermore, the owner of the organization must be associated with a role.: [AccountId]. I have given a Role to the account owner.

Comment: You can't merge contacts with two separate accounts, you'll either need to merge the accounts first or move the contacts under a single account. Keep in mind that each portal user is assigned a specific role hierarchy for the account.

Comment: @PriyankaGaikwad - Is the contact associated with an account and if so does the account that it is associated with have an owner who has a role?

Comment: Yes @Eric contact is associated with account and it does have owner who has role.

Comment: Thank you @Coldeagle. Do you have any documentation or help link which i can refer to?

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=contacts_merge.htm&language=en, I would see if merging the contacts under a single account helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can't merge contacts with two separate accounts, you'll either need to merge the accounts first or move the contacts under a single account.

Answer (score 0):

You can't merge contacts with two separate accounts, you'll either need to merge the accounts first or move the contacts under a single account. Keep in mind that each portal user is assigned a specific role hierarchy for the account.
https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=contacts_merge.htm&language=en_US